# SonarLint different bindings per module

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have opened different Java projects as modules in IntelliJ, and I'd like to bind different SonarQube projects for each one of them. But apparently, only one is applied to all modules. How could I change that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's possible with Eclipse, but currently unimplemented for IntelliJ (and VSCode) and "[Module-level services have recently been deprecated on Jetbrains plugin API side.](http://Module-level%20services%20have%20recently%20been%20deprecated%20on%20Jetbrains%20plugin%20API%20side,%20so%20it%20will%20make%20the%20implementation%20of%20this%20feature%20even%20more%20complex.)"

[Here's the feature ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-171)

The community plugin [SonarQube Analyzer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7238-sonarqube-analyzer/) seems to have this ability. See the wiki: https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/sonar-intellij-plugin#module-configuration

The user gaynaper specifically created [a fork of the official app to allow binding by vcsroots](https://github.com/gayanper/sonarlint-intellij/tree/multi_module). I haven't inspected nor tried it.